# Create shortcut from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there any way in windows XP to create a shortcut to a file from the command line?

If not what is the easiest Winapi call to create a shortcut to a file?

Comment: [create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file

Answer (score 2):

You can use the utility NirCmd
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

example

```
nircmd.exe shortcut "C\Windows:\System32\calc.exe"    "C:\Calculators" "Windows Calculator"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made ShortcutMaker.vbs for this:

```
Sub Shortcut(Application,Name,Location,Icon,Hotkey)
  Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
  If IsEmpty(Icon) Then 
    Icon = "winver.exe,0"
  End If
  If IsEmpty(Hotkey) Then 
     NoHotkey = True
  End If
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  MyTab = Split(Application,"\")
  If Name = "" Then
    Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
  End if
  Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DblQuote(Location & "\" & Name & ".lnk"))
  With objShortCut
    .TargetPath = DblQuote(Application)
    .IconLocation = Icon
    If Not(NoHotkey) Then
       .Hotkey = Hotkey
    End If
    .Save
  End With
End Sub
Sub DblQuote(Str)
  DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

You can then call Shortcut() like:

```
Call Shortcut(Application,Name,LocationFolder,OptionalIcon,OptionalHotkey)
```